# How to make round plane in VTK?

Tags: vtk

vtkPlaneSource draws quadrilateral piece of a plane. How to make it round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a vtkRegularPolygonSource with a large number of sides:

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/RegularPolygonSource